# Redirect в laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Я ввожу данные в форму и хочу, чтоб после отправки мне выводился результат обработки контроллером снизу под формой. Но я не пойму как это сделать, чтоб при обновлении страницы форма снова не отправлялась. Через редирект нашел лишь как инпут передать. Попробовал передать в редирект ссылку на контроллер, но он говорит, что не знает такого контроллера хоть я его и обозначил.

````
        return redirect()->action([IndexController::class, 'last']); 
    }
    public function last(){
        dd("OK!");
    } ```
Пробовал так, но выдает ошибку что контоллер last() - undefined
````

Answer (score 0):

В самой функции добавления вместо

```
return redirect()->action([IndexController::class, 'last']);
```

Лучше использовать

```
if(!$result) {
        return back()->withErrors(['msg' => 'Ваш текст'])->withInput();
    }
    
    return back();
```

Comment: А не подскажите, как в blade принять это?

Comment: `@if($errors->any())
<h4>{{$errors->first()}}</h4>
@endif`
Можно еще так
`@if($errors->has())
    <ul>
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif`